# cannot perform drag-n-drop python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop

I created a test in selenium and exported it in python. The test includes drag-n-drop of an element to a div. When i run the test in python the drag-n-drop cannot be performed. The code i am using for that is:

```
source_element =  self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 
'plinkTest')]")
 dest_element = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//* 
 [@id='tools_dep_jstree_id']")

actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(source_element).click_and_hold().perform()
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)

actions.move_to_element(dest_element).perform()
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(dest_element).release().perform()
```

The error i am getting is "move_to requires a web element".

Comment: Relevant HTML please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was use of find_elements_by_xpath instead of find_element_by_xpath (the first gives back a list, jus typo error) and the source element could only be found by the use of link text:

```
source_element = self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('plink')
dest_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tools_dep_jstree_id']/ul")

actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(source_element).click_and_hold().perform()

time.sleep(2)
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(dest_element).perform()

actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(dest_element).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements_by_xpath()` will returns as **list** not **WebElement**.

Change the below lines from  **find_elements_by_xpath()**

```
 source_element =  self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 
'plinkTest')]")
 dest_element = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//* 
 [@id='tools_dep_jstree_id']")
```

To **find_element_by_xpath()**

```
 source_element =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 
'plinkTest')]")
 dest_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//* 
 [@id='tools_dep_jstree_id']")
```